# Using Member Functions in a Friend Function

Tags: c++

I am trying to use...

```
int Fraction::GCD(int a, int b)
{
    for (;;)
    {
        if (a == 0)
            return b;
        b %= a;
        if (b == 0)
            return a;
        a %= b;
    }
}

int Fraction::LCD(int a, int b)
{
    return (abs(a * b) / GCD(a, b));
}
```

... which is located in the private of my Fraction class.

I am getting a compiler error " 'LCD' was not declared in this scope" when trying to call it in my overloaded friend operator...

```
Fraction operator + (const Fraction &x, const Fraction &y)
{
    Fraction temp;
    static int lcd = LCD(x.denom, y.denom); // <--
    if (lcd / x.denom != 1)
        temp.num = x.num * (lcd / x.denom);
    if (lcd / y.denom != 1)
        temp.num += y.num * (lcd / y.denom);
    temp.denom = LCD(x.denom, y.denom);
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your functions are declared as "normal" (i.e.non-static) member functions:

```
class Fraction {
    int GCD(int a, int b); 
    int GCD(int a, int b); 
    ...
public: 
    ...
};
```

If you declare your operator as friend, you can access them from this operator, but you should invoke them with an object:

```
temp.denom = temp.LCD(x.denom, y.denom);
```

If you call them without an object, like you do:

```
temp.denom = LCD(x.denom, y.denom);
```

the compiler don't find the: nothing tells him that you are speaking from a member function

Fortunately, it appears that your both functions `GCD()` and `LCD()` are in fact completly independent of the state of the Fraction object:. They only depend on their arguments.  So you could/should declare them as static.

```
class Fraction {
    static int GCD(int a, int b); 
    static int GCD(int a, int b); 
    ...
};
```

You can then call them without specifying an object:

```
temp.denom = Fraction::LCD(x.denom, y.denom);
```

Comment: When I declared them as "static int", it gave me the compiler error, "cannot declare member function 'static int Fraction::GCD(int,int)' to have static linkage [-fpermissive]."

Comment: You were right actually, I was declaring them static in the declaration and as well as the definition, when I took it off the definition it worked! Thank you! Can you elaborate on what the implementation of static does right there?

Comment: static has several meanings.  But for class members, "static" means "independent from any specific object of that class".  Here a [small tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_static_members.htm) to tell you more about it.